# output of zeros when i try to replace array elements

Tags: arrays, replace, output

```
import java.util.*;

public class helloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the array size : ");
        int size = num.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " number of array");
            int m = num.nextInt();
        }

        int repl = 0 ; 

        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ;i++) {
            repl = array[i];
            array[i] = array[array.length-1-i];
        }
        for(int i =0 ; i< array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have forgotten to ask the question. What do you expect the code to do, what is the error, if you get one, what's the expected output? You also may want to add "java" as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the array size : ");
    int size = num.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " number of array");
        int m = num.nextInt();
        array[i] = m;
    }

    int repl = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (array.length/2); i++) {
        repl = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = repl;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```